# How can I change or remove DataGridColumnHeader vertical line color wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, columnheader

How can I change DataGridColumnHeader vertical line color?

I used SeparatorBrush transparent, and SeparatorVisibility hidden, but there were not work.

I can draw border , but basic separator show continued.

How can I fix it...?

↓

[image]

```
  <Style x:Key="DataGridHeaderStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRow_2}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGrid_HeaderUnderLine}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
            <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the separator visibility to collapsed and it works.

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: I edited my question. I already set separatorVisibility to collapsed.

Comment: Your style is based on an existing style and that maybe overriding the separator visibility. Also, you have the border thickness mentioned, remove the extra styles for now, just try to hide your separators first and then add the remaining styles step by step.